# Recoding continuous variable

Tags: r, recode

I have a continuous variable. Entries 1-60 need to stay the same. NAs and 0s are coded as a number above 60.

I tried using mutate in a few different ways, but none worked. Most of the outcomes were and error or the new MH variable with nothing actually changed.

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`, you can use

- `recode()`

```r
df %>%
  mutate(y = recode(x, `88` = 0, `99` = NA_real_))
```

- `case_match()`

```r
df %>%
  mutate(y = case_match(x, 88 ~ 0, 99 ~ NA, .default = x))
```

- `case_when()`

```r
df %>%
  mutate(y = case_when(x == 88 ~ 0, x == 99 ~ NA, .default = x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `fcase`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, y := fcase(!x %in% c(88, 99), x, x == 88, 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of options at your disposal with the `tidyverse` packages (e.g., `dplyr`, `tidyr`). One option is to use `na_if` to turn the 99s into `NA` and `if_else` to turn the 88s to 0.

I have created a fake dataset below, but if you have questions about your specific dataset, you should provide a [reproducible example with your own data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

```
library(tidyverse)
a <- sample(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 99, 88), size = 30, replace = T)
b <- sample(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 99, 88), size = 30, replace = T)
c <- sample(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 99, 88), size = 30, replace = T)
df <- data.frame(a, b, c)
df

df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),  ~na_if(., 99))) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),  ~if_else(. == 88, 0, .)))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can update matching values inplace with base R

```
df$y[df$y == 99] <- NA
df$y[df$y == 88] <- 0
```